# robot_pose_ekf doesn't output

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I am trying to use robot_pose_ekf. However It doesn't work.
Here is the wtf output

```
 Input:
 * Odometry sensor
  - is NOT active
  - received 0 messages
  - listens to topic 
 * IMU sensor
  - is active
  - received 15523 messages
  - listens to topic /AHRS8_data
 * Visual Odometry sensor
 - is active
 - received 706 messages
 - listens to topic /WH_DVL_data
 Output:
  * Robot pose ekf filter
  - is active
  - sent 0 messages
  - pulishes on topics /robot_pose_ekf/odom and /tf
```

then after a while, I got the error

```
 [ERROR]filter time older than vo message buffer
```

thank you very much for your time.
regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63188/robot_pose_ekf-doesn%27t-output/) by [mihota](https://answers.ros.org/users/3807/mihota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a possibility of mis match in the frame on which Odometry sensor publishes data and the frame on which ROBOT_POSE_EKF expects the data.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0